# mixitup counting visible items on initial start after page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, mixitup

I am playing with [mixitup](https://mixitup.kunkalabs.com) to sort items.

I can count items visible after I press a sort or filter buttons:

```
$('#collection').on('mixEnd', function(e, state){
    var countvisible = $("#container> tr[style='']").length;
    console.log('Sorted! ' + countvisible );

    $('#current_count').text(countvisible);
});
```

### What I need: get a count of visible items on page load

but the `on('mixEnd') does NOT ignite during the initialization of the mixitup on page load.

How to do it? I can just use `on PageLoad` sit some delay, but it doesn't seem as a good practice.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's a little late, but if it can help, I found the answer in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/christoffwalker/pen/YqmYvm).

It's a huge one, but in your case, you would only need this:

```
$('#collection').on('mixEnd', function(e, state) {
    $('#current_count').html(state.totalShow);
});
```

The `state.totalShow` is the key ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do you try to use the visible selector ?

```
$('#collection').on('mixEnd', function(e, state){
    var countvisible = $("#container> tr[style='']:visible").length;
    console.log('Sorted! ' + countvisible );

    $('#current_count').text(countvisible);
});
```